# How do I change my pawn's vocation?

Tags: dragons-dogma

How can I change the vocation of my pawn? I know how to change the vocation of the others but not his.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I haven't played in quite some time, but I'm fairly certain you can do this at any of the inns, where you would be able to change your vocation as well by talking to the innkeeper(if I'm remembering it correctly). You just tap whichever button it is that would normally let you switch between you and your pawn in your inventory menus. Should allow you to do it. If you can't do it at the inn, I would try at the Pawn's Guild. Like I said, haven't played in forever, but I do love this game. (edit- You may very well have to make it to Gran Soren before you can change your pawn's vocation)

Comment: Yes, you change your pawn's vocation at the inn. There should be an on-screen prompt for switching focus between you and your pawn.